# Interpreting a list of free monads vs. interpreting a free monad of a list

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz

I'm learning functional programming and have some (maybe obvious, but not for me :) ) question about monad. Every monad is an applicative functor. Applicative functor in turn can be defined as a higher-kinded type as follows (`pure` method omitted):

```
trait ApplicativeFunctor[F[_]]{
   def ap[A](fa: F[A])(f: F[A => B]): F[B]
}
```

As far as I understand this typeclass means that we can take two values of `F[A]`, `F[B]` and a function `(A, B) => C` and construct `F[C]`.

This property enables us to construct the list reversing function:

```
def reverseApList[F[_]: ApplicativeFunctor, A](lst: List[F[A]]): F[List[A]]
```

Let we have

```
trait SomeType[A]
```

Now consider

```
type MyFree[A] = Free[SomeType, A] 
val nt: NaturalTransformation[SomeType, Id]
val lst: List[MyFree[Int]]
```

***QUESTION:*** Why are `lst.map(_.foldMap(nt))` and `reverseApList(lst).foldMap(nt)` the same? Is it following from applicative functor laws or there is another reason? Can you please explain?

Comment: The first signature doesn't tell anything about `C`. What you described is called `map2`, not `ap`. Furthermore, I don't quite get what's going on with `reverse`. Are you really reversing anything, or is it a typo and you meant "traverse"?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Take a look at `Apply` in scalaz. This is defined as `ap`. I just said that `map2` can be gotten from `ap`. By reversing I meant making `F[List[A]]` from `List[F[A]]`. Such order reversing can only be done for application functors, not just functors...

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Just a note... in scalaz this is `apply2`, not `map2` :)

Comment: @AndreyTyukin The closest to reverse is the function `Applicative.sequence` btw.

Comment: Thanks for looking up the names again, that definitely makes the question clearer. Indeed, it's `apply2` in scalaz. A similar function is called [map2 in cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/Apply.html#map2[A,B,Z](fa:F[A],fb:F[B])(f:(A,B)=%3EZ):F[Z]) , and also in Bjarnason/Chiusano , if I'm not confusing anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It follows from the laws of Traversable functors.

First, realize that `_.foldMap(nt)` is itself a natural transformation from `MyFree` to `Id`. Moreover, by the very definition of what it means to be a free monad, it is required to be a *monad homomorphism<sup>1</sup>* (for any `nt`).

Let's start from your

```
reverseApList(lst).foldMap(nt)
```

which can also be written as

```
lst.sequence.foldMap(nt)
```

Now we are going to apply the [naturality law of Traversable functors](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/fdbf1e3696b03929c39f3cf688460d2169116999/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Traverse.scala#L175-L186), with `_.foldMap(nt)` as the natural transformation `nat`. For it to be applicable, our natural transformation has to be an *applicative homomorphism*, which is expressed by [the two extra conditions](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/fdbf1e3696b03929c39f3cf688460d2169116999/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Traverse.scala#L177-L178). But we already know that our natural transformation is a monad homomorphism, which is even stronger (preserves more structure) than an applicative homomorphism. We may therefore proceed to apply this law and obtain

```
lst.map(_.foldMap(nt)).sequence : Id[List[Int]]
```

Now using just the laws in the linked scalaz file it is provable (although in a roundabout way) that this last `sequence` through `Id` is actually a no-op. We get

```
lst.map(_.foldMap(nt))          : List[Id[Int]]
```

which is what we wanted to show.

---

<sup>1</sup> : A natural transformation `h: M ~> N` is a monad homomorphism if it preserves the monadic structure, i.e. if it satisfies

- for any `a: A`:
  `h(Monad[M].point[A](a)) = Monad[N].point[A](a)`
- for any `ma: M[A]` and `f: A => M[B]`:
  `h(ma.flatMap(f)) = h(ma).flatMap(a => h(f(a)))`

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I still cannot prove that the second precondition of the `naturality` law you linked is hold :(. I found that the `FreeInstance` contains the `Monad[Free]` definition with `bind` implemented as `flatMap`. So `ap` is also expressed as  `Free.flatMap`. But how does it make `_.foldMap(nt)` satisfy the second naturality precondition? Thanks :)

Comment: The two extra conditions are the definition of what it means for a natural transformation to be an _applicative homomorphism_. OTOH, by definition of what it means to be a free monad, `_.foldMap(nt)` is required to be a _monad homomorphism_ for any `nt: F ~> M` with `M` a monad (`h: N ~> M` is a monad homomorphism if `h(na.flatMap(f)) = h(na).flatMap(a => h(f(a)))`, plus the same condition for `point` as for applicative homomorphism), so it better hold for `scalaz.Free` (otherwise it's not a free monad). It is easy to show that every monad homomorphism is an applicative homomorphism.